# Saving form data to local storage giving undefined

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, local-storage

I have a form in wordpress where users can input their data. I'd like for this data to be saved by use of local storage. But when I go to a page were the form is not shown and I go back I get " undefined ".

My code works only if on the next page the form is shown.
Example: if I fill in the frontpage form and go to Page3 were there is no form and then go back to the frontpage the form is filled in with "undefined".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).unload(saveSettings);
        loadSettings();
});
        // This will store and autofill the fields value on next page
        function loadSettings() {
            $('#searchbox1').val(localStorage.searchbox1);
            $('#first').val(localStorage.first);
            $('#first2').html(localStorage.first2);
            $('#second').val(localStorage.second);
            $('#second2').html(localStorage.second2);
            $('#third').val(localStorage.third);
            $('#third2').html(localStorage.third2);
        }

        function saveSettings() {
            localStorage.searchbox1 = $('#searchbox1').val();
            localStorage.first = $('#first').val();
            localStorage.first2 = $('#first2').html();
            localStorage.second = $('#second').val();
            localStorage.second2 = $('#second2').html();
            localStorage.third = $('#third').val();
            localStorage.third2 = $('#third2').html();
        }
```

my html form

```
<form id="myForm" >

<input type="text" id="searchbox1" placeholder="Example: 22x32x7" value="" name="searchbox1" id="s" />
<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="" />
<div class="form-3input-boxes-wraper col-sm-5">
  <div class="form-3input-boxes">

    <label for="insideDiameter">insideDiameter mm</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="first" name="first" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="x" />

    <label for="outsideDiameter">outsideDiameter mm</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="second" name="second" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="x" />

    <label for="width">width</label>
    <input type="text" value="" id="third" name="s" />
  </div>    
    <span id="first2"></span>
    <span id="second2"></span>
    <span id="third2"></span>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is localStorage??

Comment: function hasLocalStorage() {
     if (localStorage)
         return “Local Storage: Supported”;
        else
        return “Local Storage: Not Supported”;
 }

Comment: window.location.reload(); after savesetting